# How to overlay a UIImage using drawAtPoint()?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

The following code draws some text over an image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

NSString *stamp = @"Internal Use Only";
[stamp drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32]];

UIImage *stampedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If the code is executed again using a different string, both strings are combined and not legible. How can I make this so drawAtPoint() overlays the previous string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by rendering a UITextView. These know how to draw themselves via their layer property and can display multiple lines (added bonus!):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
NSString *stamp = @"Internal Use Only";
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 80);
textview.frame = frame;
textview.text = stamp;
textview.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:32];
[textview.layer renderInContext:context];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make copy of original image every time you want to draw a text on it. In other words you must keep the original version of your image.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the original image will be modified by others. I have to place a stamp in the same region of the image. This is why I want to somehow "erase" the old stamp and render a new one on top of it.

Comment: By others? You can't just erase stamp from the image, the only way you can do that is to save the original part of your image beneath your stamp. Earse means - return image to some previouse condition, so, you just have to "remember" this condition which you want to restore. You can save whole image or just some part - it will depends on your stamp metrics...

Comment: So I get an image and I stamp the image using this code on the upper right corner at (10, 10) using today's date. Then I send this stamped image to another process who draws something else (say a red circle in the center). Tomorrow I get the image, containing the red circle and my original stamp. I need to re-stamp this image with today's date. But if I run this code again on the image, it will render on top of the original date. So how to stamp the image again so it completely overlays the original (yesterday's) date?

Comment: in this case you'd better to use two separated images: original image and image with stamp and red circle. There is no magic algorithm which can recover original image information under your stamp.

Comment: In case of using two separate image you dont need to merge it every time, but only if you really need it to be merged, for example to serialize it as flat image. Remember you can display these images separated using two UIImageView controls  one beneath other.